# Java Threads accessing a field of an Object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

I got a question in an Interview asking as below:-

In Java, an object having a field, as given below...

```
public class MyObject
{
    int count=0;

    public synchronized void m()
    {
        for(int j=0; j< 1000; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-> "+j);
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" completed ->"+count);
    }
}
```

Here, the field "*count*" is accessed in a synchronized method, and the field is not declared volatile.

What will be the actual behavior if a Thread *t1* accessing the method *m()* which is synchronized and using field "count" within it, and simultaneously another Thread *t2* tries to access the field "count" directly ?

Comment: For thread t2, when you say access do you mean read only?

Comment: yes, read only. will it read updated value or there will be race condition?

Answer (score 1):

`t1` will have visibility of the most up-to-date value of `count` flushed to main memory, reading it when it enters the `synchronized` block, and writing it back when it leaves; the value it prints at the end will always be 1000 more than the value it read.

`t2` will read the value of `count` at some time; it is allowed to keep a cached value. Any updates to the value of count may be flushed to main memory immediately, later, or never.

Answer (score -2):

There will be race condition. As **ONLY** the method "**m**" is thread safe. Here  you can find the detail about [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition)